# How can I edit this login/logoff dropdown menu for Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've hit a wall trying to create a dropdown login modal for my wordpress website. 
Currently, when a user selects the login button the login modal is displayed but upon successful login, alongside the login button (of which the label changes to the users name), another button labelled 'dropdown' is displayed with the drop down options to go to the 'my account' page and to logout (image shown below).

[image]

What I want is for the user to select the login button, login in successfully and the login button label changes from 'login' to the users name then when the select the now button with their name on it the drop down menu with options to go to 'my account' or 'logout' is shown there. So there is no second button, only one. I hope I have explained this clear enough, I'm essentially attempting to combine the two javascript functions I have. Please any suggestions of how to fix this is very welcome because I have spent days trying to! Thank you so very much in advance!

Javascript: (this calls for the initial login modal)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //show the login dialog box on click
  $('a#show_login').on('click', function(e){
      $('body').prepend('<div class="login_overlay"></div>');
      $('form#login').fadeIn(500);
      $('div.login_overlay, form#login a.close').on('click', function(){
          $('div.login_overlay').remove();
          $('form#login').hide();
      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });

  //perform AJAX login on form submit
  $('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
      $('form#login p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
          data: {
              'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
              'username': $('form#login #username').val(),
              'password': $('form#login #password').val(),
              'security': $('form#login #security').val() },
          success: function(data){
              $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
              if (data.loggedin == true){
                  document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
              }
          }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Javascript & HTML: (calls for the dropdown)

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <a class="login_button" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>"><?php global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); echo $current_user->user_firstname ;?></a>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="login_button">Dropdown</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/cart/my-account">MY ACCOUNT</a>
            <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">LOGOUT</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // when the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content
        function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }
        //close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('.login_button')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
              var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
              if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
              }
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I would use is taking advantage of WordPress hooks. Using the hook for the drop-down, simply hook in get_currentuserinfo();

This request will display the user's login name.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by this.. do you have the code version of your answer?